# Re-render on state change returns blank

Tags: reactjs

I have a list which users can add items to.  The user can then 'like' any item in the list, and the number of likes is displayed on the item. When I click 'like' on an item, however, the entire list disappears. The component's state has all the correct, updated data, so I'm thinking the problem may be related to the component rendering too soon. How can I make sure the component (Category.jsx) re renders properly once the state is updated?

App.js (parent component)

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    wentWell: [],
    wellValue: '',
  }

  updateWellValue = e => this.setState({ wellValue: e.target.value });

  wellSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      wentWell: [...this.state.wentWell, {value: this.state.wellValue, likes: 0, dislikes: 0}],
      wellValue: ''
    })
  }

wellUpvote = upvoteIndex => {
    const wentWell = Object.assign({}, this.state.wentWell);
    wentWell[upvoteIndex].likes += 1;
    return this.setState({ wentWell });
  }  


  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Title />
        <div className="container">
          <Category 
            name="Went Well" 
            items={this.state.wentWell}
            inputValue={this.state.wellValue}
            updateInput={this.updateWellValue}
            submit={this.wellSubmit}
            upvote={this.wellUpvote}
          />

</>
    );
  }
}
```

Category.jsx (child component)

```
class Category extends Component {
  state = {
    items: this.props.items
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if(nextProps.items !== prevState.items){
      return ({ items: nextProps.items }) // <- this is setState equivalent
    }
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div className="category">
        <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>

        {/* ------ FORM (INPUT AND SUBMIT BUTTON) ------ */}
        <form onSubmit={e => this.props.submit(e)}>
          <input 
            placeholder="Enter note here"
            value={this.props.inputValue} 
            onChange={e => this.props.updateInput(e)}
          />
          <button type="submit" className={this.props.colorId}>Submit</button>
        </form> 

        {/* ------ MAPPED OUT ITEMS ------ */}
        {this.state.items.length > 0 ? 
          this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (<Item 
              key={`item-${index}`} 
              index={index}
              upvote={this.props.upvote}
              item={item}
            />);
          }) : <h3>(Nothing here)</h3>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Category;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use `Object.assign` on an array.

`const wentWell = Object.assign({}, this.state.wentWell);`

Try doing

`const tempWentWell = [...this.state.wentWell]`